# Make a whole Row editable on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, tablecolumn

I want to make a whole Row editable...e.g if user selected column 1 than click on edit button the table will show the whole row in editable form...it will be great if any one can give only code upon button event.

Comment: *"I want to make a whole Row editable.."*  Go for it!  All the best.  *"..it will be great if any one can give only code.."* ..so not a link to a basic tutorial?  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a whole Row editable...e.g if user selected column 1
>   than click on edit button the table will show the whole row in
>   editable form...it will be great if any one can give only code upon
>   button event.

- I think have to use `JToggleButton`, because (`JButton`s) simple click is immediatelly finalized in comparing with `JToggleButton` (has two states)
- for `JTable` have to set proper SelectionMode and to override `public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {`